# Application certification for Microsoft Office VSTO solutions

Tags: security

A potential client is very interested by a VSTO product we developed. However, their IT department is concerned wether they should trust this sofware. Mainly, they are worried it could expose a security breach into their system.

We are a small company, with very little reputation.
Our apps are signed via en EV Code certificate. What are the other steps we could take to help convince these gate keepers? We were thinking of certifying our software, for example we are aware of the [Windows Application Certification Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/mt186449), but as far as we understand it does not apply to VSTOs?

Hope this is the right place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't seek for technical measures, you cannot give a 100% guarantee that your software has no security bugs, especially in the presence of 3rd party components.

The only real measure which counts here is the contract your company will offer the client (including general terms and conditions). There is the place to give certain guarantees about the security of your software, how you will react in case an unintentional security issue arises, and the insurances your company has for worst case scenarios. Another thing clients might expect from you is some QM certificate, for example, an ISO 9000 certification, but that may depend a lot on the specific region where you produce and sell your software, as well as the business domain.

(Note IANAL, and this is not legal advice, you should definitely contact a lawyer for this. Additionally, you can try to ask on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will definitely consider this for other matters. In the current situation, the client is a global firm much bigger than our startup company. The impact of any sort of exposure would be huge to them (reputation, etc), and we surely would never be able to repair for the damage (in terms of means, and money). So the contents of the contract has little effect. They are not looking for an insurance policy, but a guarantee we meet some sort of standards. Maybe a third-party company could verify our code?

Comment: @Ama: lots of companies are satisfied when your company can show them a Quality Management certificate (like ISO 9000, for example) - not for the individual piece of software, but for your processes to develop it. And if your client is a large global firm, believe me, they *are* looking for your companies insurance.

Comment: Contract clauses is definitely a requirement, but not enought. I'll investigate ISO... thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have a penetration testing firm test your software and issue a report.

If you have a particular client in mind, ask them who does their pen testing and offer to use the same firm.

That way you assure them that your software is tested to the same standards as their own.

Plus you expand the question in their minds. It's no longer "Is this software secure" it's "How secure is this software in comparison to other software we use?". A much lower bar to hit.

You might also find that they are assured if you have other big clients "Well its secure enough for MI5!" of course you have to get your foot in the door somewhere first.

Comment: That is surely a good idea for Web applications.

Comment: or any applications

Comment: I like your thinking. And "Pen test" is the terminology I was looking for.. thanks!